# Register new mime-type in ColdFusion (Java)

Tags: java, coldfusion

My users are going to be uploading files with a .EXP extension. In ColdFusion on Windows 2003 I'm using getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType() to make sure that the file that they upload is of the correct mime-type, which will be text/plain. The issue I'm having is that no matter where I register the mime-type on the server, getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType() will return blank since it doesn't know about the .EXP file extension. What is the trick to get ColdFusion to see this file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY!!!!

In order for getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType() to recognize the new filetype, you must edit the file:

```
<ColdFusion-home>\runtime\lib\mime.types
```

In my case this file was located at:

```
C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\lib\mime.type
```

I opened file file and found this line:

```
text/plain asc txt
```

All I had to do was add my extension to the end like so:

```
text/plain asc txt exp
```

Then I restart the ColdFusion service and invoking getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType() return text/plain.

Comment: if anyone knows of a way to register a new mime type by using java and not editing the file directly, PLEASE let me know. while this is a fix, it won't be possible to do this on a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

> the MIME types supported are defined
>   in your webserver, whether it's IIS,
>   Apache or other. Apache MIME types can
>   be configured in the mime.types files
>   in the httpd/conf directory. The
>   getMimeTypes() method communicates
>   with the web server and returns the
>   associated MIME type for the file.

http://chris.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm/2009/8/12/Securely-Serving-Files-via-CFContent

Comment: @Henry: AFAIK, the MIME type you set in the server only affects downloads, not uploads.

Comment: For uploads, MIME type is provided by the Browser, I believe, and Browser determine MIME type by file extension only, so it is not trustworthy.

Answer (score -1):

How about simply checking the request headers for the MIME type?

```
<cfset hrd = GetHttpRequestData()>
<cfdump var="#hrd#">
```

You'll get a struct that contains all data the client sent, including the content type of the uploaded file.

In any case, trusting the MIME type or the file extension the client sends you is dangerous, I would rather check the file with some other means (RegEx, for example, or a parser) to make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: trying to invoke GetRequestData() returned and error stating that it was a valid function.

Comment: Whoops. My bad, I screwed up the function name. Corrected.